# let with data constructor

Tags: haskell

I have these statements:

```
data SL a = SR (Integer -> (a, Integer))
    deriving(Show)

instance Monad SL where
    return k = SR (\st -> (k, st))

xx::SL Integer
xx = return 4
```

Then I do:

```
let SR f = xx
```

Now I have:

```
xx :: SL Integer
f :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
```

but I cannot understand why. Maybe I'm missing the syntactic meaning of `let DATACONSTRUCTOR ..`.

Can you help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let SR f = xx` means that `SR f` should be equal to `xx`. So,

```
SR f = xx                   -- let
     = return 4             -- def. xx
     = SR (\st -> (4, st))  -- def. return
```

and thus

```
f = \st -> (4, st)  -- remove SR on both sides
```

which, in this context, is of type `Integer -> (Integer, Integer)` because of `SR :: a -> Integer -> (a, Integer)` and `xx :: SL Integer`.

Answer (score 5):

`let` and `where` are pattern matches too, like `case`, but with only one alternative. So for example a `let` expression:

```
let SR f = xx in ...
```

is like the following `case` expression:

```
case xx of
  SR f -> ...
```

Most people simply use `let` and `where` to do simple variable bindings, so they don't realize that they are pattern matches. However, a variable binding is just a special case of pattern match (an identifier in a pattern match matches everything and binds the value to the variable).

Also, most pattern matches need more than one alternative, so `let` is not applicable. Even when you only want to match a particular constructor, doing an incomplete pattern match is not a good idea. However, there are certain cases when one alternative is a complete match, for example, a tuple match `(x, y)`, or, as in your case, a datatype with only one constructor.